# Making images appear in same position on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have made my website and positioned the icons so that they fit perfectly on desktop as far as I can tell, but on mobile it seems to appear with the icons under neath the background.

Live version http://viralpvp.net/
Pastebin to code: https://pastebin.com/9ibFp84G

I believe it is this section where I went wrong but I am not sure so please let me know if you can help!

```
width:400px;
height:400px;
max-width:100%;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in your code, you are using fixed values for `px`.
On a desktop, (and when designed on a desktop,) it may look fine for you, but since a mobile phone does not have that many pixels in width, it will push the images up or down, depending on their original order.

Basically your images are too big for mobile, because their size is fixed at 400px by 400px

To fix that, I suggest changing the images' fixed widths to a resizable unit.
One example of a resizable unit is `vw`.
`vw` stands for viewport, and is based on your screen's width.
It is represented numerically from 0-100, basically percentage.

The difference between percentage `(%)` and `vw` is that percentages are relative sizes of the containing body or container, while `vw` will always be based on the viewport.

Below is an example of viewport usage.
View the example in full screen and resize your desktop browser, and see what it does. It will resize the image along with it.

With `vw`, you need to set the minimum widths and heights for all of your `vw` stuff because it may get too tiny on a mobile device. For that, use `min-width` and `min-height`.

Hope I helped!

Mark

```css
#vwTest
  {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vw;
  }
  
#vwTest2
  {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vw;
  }
```

```html
<div id="vwTest">
 </div>
<div id="vwTest2">
 </div>
```